# RMSE value on the example of randomForrest

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am watching one of the solutions for House Prices Kaggle competition. I would like to know how do you get RMSE value from this:

Subset the train rows and selected features

```
dt.train <- fulldt %>% filter(Set == "Train") %>% select("Id", "OverallQual", "TotalArea", "AreaAbvground", "GarageArea", "TotalBaths", "YearBuilt", "Neighborhood", "MSSubClass", "FireplaceQu", "ExterQual", "KitchenQual", "BsmtQual", "HouseStyle") %>% mutate(SalePrice = log(raw.train$SalePrice))
```

Same for the test features

```
dt.test <- fulldt %>% filter(Set == "Test") %>%
                        select("Id", "OverallQual", "TotalArea", "AreaAbvground", "GarageArea", "TotalBaths", "YearBuilt", 
                               "Neighborhood", "MSSubClass", "FireplaceQu", "ExterQual", "KitchenQual", "BsmtQual", "HouseStyle")
```

Random Forest model

```
fit <- randomForest(SalePrice ~ ., data = dt.train, importance = T)
```

Use new model to predict SalePrice values from the test set

```
pred <- exp(predict(fit , newdata = dt.test))
```

How do you get RMSE value from pred ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate the RMSE of the training and test rows based on the minimal example iris data:

```r
library(tibble)
library(randomForest)
#> randomForest 4.6-14
#> Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.
library(yardstick)
#> For binary classification, the first factor level is assumed to be the event.
#> Use the argument `event_level = "second"` to alter this as needed.

train_df <- head(iris, 100)
test_df <- tail(iris, 50)

model <- randomForest(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = train_df, importance = T)

# Test RMSE
tibble(
  truth = predict(model, newdata = test_df),
  predicted = test_df$Sepal.Length
) %>%
  rmse(truth, predicted)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 rmse    standard       0.836

# Train RMSE
tibble(
  truth = predict(model, newdata = train_df),
  predicted = train_df$Sepal.Length
) %>%
  rmse(truth, predicted)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 rmse    standard       0.265
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I am not sure what should be "truth" and what "predicted" in rmse() function in this example: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.coms/358187_2157f6fed1e243d998c5cae2af2eca55.html . It looks like the code is not finished.

Comment: `rmse(pred_df, truth, predicted)` will use the columns named `truth` and `predicted` of the table `pred_df` to calculate RMSE.

Comment: `caret` is deprecated. I would use `tidymodels` instead if you want to learn something new.

Comment: In your case this would be `tibble(pred = exp(predict(fit , newdata = dt.test)), truth = dt.test$SalePrice`

Comment: The problem is I dont have dt.test$SalePrice, and im not sure which one to take for truth Sale Price value and from where. If you can check here: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.coms/358187_2157f6fed1e243d998c5cae2af2eca55.html

Comment: The truth is the column in the test table, the predicted is the output from the model using the test table

Comment: I understand that. But the problem is I don't see SalePrice variable (column) anywhere in the test data-set of the House Prices Kaggle data-set. So the code: `tibble(pred = exp(predict(fit , newdata = dt.test)), truth = dt.test$SalePrice`   does not provide truth variable.  In fact the SalePrice variable is only present in the train data-set provided by Kaggle. I don't understand.

Comment: Here is the link , I just don't understand how to create rmse () from this : https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/358187_2157f6fed1e243d998c5cae2af2eca55.html

Comment: Seems that `fulldt$SalePrice` has the truth values instead. They were discarded from `dt.test` in the `select` command at the modelling section